# Automatic power switching between two DC sources with a switch to charging in the second position

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit

I am designing a circuit which will automatically switch to be powered by a single 18650 when the other voltage source is disconnected. It will use a DPDT switch, the second position of which will shut off power to the Arduino from both sources and power a 5V charging module for the 18650.

I have scoured this site for info, and found an IC which I believe is perfect for the automatic power switch, an [LTC4412](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4412fb.pdf) which drives a P channel MOSFET.

I have modified an example circuit found on the datasheet for my purpose, and have several questions:

- As the MOSFET gate will be closed, will the IC have any affect on the circuit in position 1?
- Can C<sub>OUT</sub> be any capacitor, so long as it is rated for >5V?
- Does any of this stand out as being terribly misinformed?

Many thanks.

[image: schematic]

Comment: You must never try to design a switch without knowing the voltage, current, and impedances with tolerances for each interface. Then define the max temp rise. When this is done with logic and analog values, multiple solutions become obvious, such as eliminating the redundant DPDT